# Downloading image is always corrupted (Python urllib)

Tags: python, image, urllib

I have a project in which I need to download an image using python. Here is the URL: http://nastaliqonline.ir/NastaliqOnline.ir.aspx?53789.2200193.
For some reason, every time I try to download it, no matter what method I use, `urllib.request.urlretrieve`, `requests`, nothing works. If I try to save it without the .jpg extension, it will open in chrome with HTML reading a runtime error. I really have no idea why, because the link is to an image, not an HTML page. [Here](https://pastebin.com/YEcn64H4)'s the error message that it gives me if that's any help. I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1):

The image you provided didn't work for me, so I picked a random image and able to retrieve it using the following code:

```
import requests
import certifi
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
main_url = "https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg"

r = http.request('GET', main_url)
r.status
open("image.jpeg", "wb").write(r.data)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted your comment, but my whole issue was that downloading that image doesn't work. When you say my image it didn't work, do you mean the URL didn't open an image or when you tried to download the image using your above code you had an error?

Comment: I am unable to open your link in browser itself.

Comment: Interesting. It must be something about that link that makes it impossible to download the image because I've been able to download other images